# Slowdown on RetroArch SNES emulation when using shaders

Tags: drivers, ati, games, emulation

New Ubuntu installation, first time Linux user.

When I turn on shaders and filters on the emulators video options the games become unplayable because of slowdown.Is the problem with Gallium 0.4 on AMD BARTS driver because this worked on windows with AMDs drivers?
HD6850, i5 2500k so it's not an issue of hardware not being powerful enough

Comment: Linux + AMD + EMU = FAIL IMHO ... If you can find an nVidia card you'll likely have better luck.

Answer (score 1):

fixed by going to ATIs drivers